# kill and suspend job in 1 command

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill

I'm trying to kill and suspend 2 seperate jobs in one command.

```
$ jobs
[1] Running                      ./jobs2 & 
[2] Running                      ./jobs1 &
[3] Running                      ./jobs3 &
```

I'm using this command :

```
kill ./jobs2 | kill -stop ./jobs1
```

This should be the final result:

```
$ jobs
[2]+ Stopped                                 ./jobs1
[3]- Running                                 ./jobs3
```

However, it's not working as expected.

Comment: Does it need to be one command? You have 2 commands. Can it just be one line?

Comment: Does it work if you scale it back to killing one job?

Comment: well yes it has to be one line @ctrl-alt-delor. Doesn't the `&&` make it as one command since its repeating the process ?

Comment: No `;`, `&&`, `||`, `|`, `&`, and new-line, are all used to separate commands. There will be a new process for each command (except that kill is a shell built in). But why does it need to be one command?

Comment: Isn't more efficient to use less commands ? That's what my teacher told us.

Comment: `;`, `&&`, `||`, `|`, `&`, and new-line, are all used to separate commands. They are seperate commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
kill -stop %2 && kill %1
```

Example:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 2284
$ sleep 200 &
[2] 2325
$ sleep 300 &
[3] 2366
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 100 &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 200 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 300 &
$ kill -stop %2 && kill %1
[1]   Terminated              sleep 100

[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 200
$ jobs
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 200
[3]-  Running                 sleep 300 &
```